# Using a different db table on a "not in" clause

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have a table "SIS" in an X database.

in database Y, I would like to do "not in (select cod_sis from SIS)".

How could I do this in PDI??

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LookUp` step then `Filter` not found matching.

In the attached, I am looking for all customers (from a table in a database) which do NOT have any orders (from an other table in an other database):

For each customer, the `Stream Lookup` fetch any order [the Lookup step input box] with a matching customerNumber. It then return the customerNumber [as read in the orders table]. If no order was found, it returns the Default [here Empty]. For clarity this, field is renamed `in_X_database`. Then the `Filter row` step discards the rows with Empty `in_X_database`.

[image]